# Wordpress Post Date, shows month by number and text

Tags: wordpress, date

I am having troubles with my Worpress post date. As the picture shows, I can publish the post with 01-Jan etc. I only want to post the month with text, and no numbers. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This information isn't actually seen on the front end, if that is what you are worried about? It's just for the reference of those posting. The date is then stored in the format if `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (i.e. `2013-12-10 15:11:35`). When you output the post you can then format the date as you wish using the the built in `the_date()` function.

Comment: Hmm... The dateformat under general settings it set to "Desember 10, 2013". But however the posts seems to have wrong date... "Wednesday, 12 Desember 2013" is set as date. My page: http://minerva.hivolda.no/~H13_MID126_902/produkt/ See below "Siste nytt". Onsdag, tirsdag means day on Norwegian.

Comment: I see what you mean. What you need to look at is the PHP source that is creating that page. It's possible that the date format has been explicitly set in there, especially if you are using a non-custom theme, so the format under 'Settings -> General' is ignored.

Comment: Thanks! :) It was set as "('l, n F Y')" in the index.php, and needed to be ('l, j F Y').

Comment: No problem. I'll add that as an answer and would be greatful if you could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that the date on the front end was displayed wrong. Therefore, I suggest you look at the PHP source that is creating that page.

It's possible that the date format has been explicitly set in there, especially if you are using a non-custom theme, so the format under 'Settings -> General' could be ignored.